# mongoDB connection returning null value

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Below my code which is returning value as null.

ConfigurationFile.java

```
package config;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

@Configuration
public class ConfigurationFile {
private static MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
public @Bean(name="mongoTemplate")
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate()throws Exception{
    mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(new       MongoClient("localhost",27017),"Test");
    System.out.println("mongoTemplateValue1--> " + mongoTemplate);
    return mongoTemplate;

}

public static MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() {
    System.out.println("mongoTemplateValue-->" + mongoTemplate);
    return mongoTemplate;
}

}
```

Client.java

```
package client;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;


import config.ConfigurationFile;

import extraction.Extractor;

public class Client {
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public static void main(String[] args){
    Client c = new Client();
    c.sample();

}

private void sample(){
    SetupMongoDb();
}

private void SetupMongoDb() {
    if (mongoTemplate == null) {
        System.out.println("insideSetup");
        mongoTemplate = ConfigurationFile.getMongoTemplate();
    }
}

}
```

I am unable to get the mongoTemplate value. Below the output
insideSetup
mongoTemplateValue-->null

Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `mongoTemplate()` method is never being called because you are not actually creating Spring Context when starting your application with `Client.main()`.
Need to learn how Spring Framework works, specifically how to [create application context](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/load-spring-application-context-file-java-swing-application). Then you'll need to point your context to your configuration file and use autowiring to obtain your `MongoTemplate`.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationFile {
@Bean(name="mongoTemplate")
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate()throws Exception{
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(new MongoClient("localhost",27017),"Test");

    return mongoTemplate;

 }
}
```

Then just use the autowired field:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

  @Autowired
  private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  public doSomething() {
    //Use your mongoTemplate
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using @Bean(name="mongoTemplate"). will that not be enough?

Comment: @Syed no, it doesn't do anything because you don't start Spring properly.